# import error when using python dlib

Tags: python, git, import, face-recognition, dlib

I'm following the instructions on this page: http://www.learnopencv.com/facial-landmark-detection/

> 1.Download a copy from github
>
> git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git
>
> Build examples ( OSX / Linux )
>
> cd dlib/examples
>
> mkdir build
>
> cd build
>
> cmake ..
>
> cmake --build . --config Release
>
> Compile dlib python module
>
> cd dlib/python_examples
>
> ./compile_dlib_python_module.bat

P.S. on this step, i didn't find that file in my python_examples folder so I googled and downloaded one and used it.

> export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/dlib/python_examples:$PYTHONPATH

Next, I went to terminal and added that line to the bottom my my .bash_profile file.

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/leoli/dlib/python_examples:$PYTHONPATH
```

At last, I typed `python -c "import dlib" in terminal but received this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(./dlib.so, 2): Library not loaded: libboost_python.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/leoli/dlib/python_examples/dlib.so
  Reason: unsafe use of relative rpath libboost_python.dylib in ./dlib.so with restricted binary
```

I am using OSX 10.11.5

Answer (score 1):

For using dlib with python, follow instructions in readme.txt:

> COMPILING DLIB Python API
>   Before you can run the Python example programs you must compile dlib. 
>   Type:
>   python setup.py install    or type
>   python setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS    
>   if you have a CPU that supports AVX instructions, since this makes some
>   things run faster.

And may be you will need some dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-python-dev cmake
```